# Can't update a widget state inside a List or a Map

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change the color of a text field that is created and added to a map through a function called addFields() but with no success..
Whereas when I add the Text Field directly without a function or a map the color changes as expected.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong since I'm new to Flutter and programing in general..
If anyone can help I'd be very appreciated.
thanks..

here is my code:

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //
  @override
  void initState() {
    addFields();
    super.initState();
  }

  final Map<int, TextField> fields = {};
  //
  Color problemColor = const Color(0xff4caf50);
  Color noProblemColor = const Color(0xff4caf50);

  //
  void addFields() {
    final newTextField = TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(filled: true, fillColor: problemColor),
      onChanged: ((val) {
        setState(() {
          problemColor = const Color(0xfff44336);
        });
      }),
    );
    fields[0] = newTextField;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('problemColor = $problemColor');
    print('noProblemColor = $noProblemColor');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            fields[0]!,
            TextField(
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration(filled: true, fillColor: noProblemColor),
              onChanged: ((val) {
                setState(() {
                  noProblemColor = const Color(0xfff44336);
                });
              }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `StatefulWidget` to rebuild the UI, you should know some common functionality about how it works:

1. The `initState()` method gets called only once when your page is getting build for the first time.
2. The `setState()` method triggers rebuild of the `StatefulWidget` (build method) which rebuilds all components (widget) under build method.
3. When you try to call `setState()` from `TextField` which is inside the map, it does not rebuild the color of `TextField` because it is outside the scope of build method.
   You can toggle the color of `TextField` which is inside the scope of build method through `setState()` method of `TextField` which is inside the map.

[See this video to understand more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqCMFXEmf3w).

Run this code to understand more

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //
  @override
  void initState() {
    addFields();
    super.initState();
  }

  final Map<int, TextField> fields = {};
  //
  Color problemColor = const Color(0xff4caf50);
  Color noProblemColor = const Color(0xff4caf50);
  bool toggleColor = false;

  //
  void addFields() {
    final newTextField = TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(filled: true, fillColor: noProblemColor),
      onChanged: ((val) {
        setState(() {
          toggleColor = !toggleColor;
          problemColor = const Color(0xfff44336);
        });
      }),
    );
    fields[0] = newTextField;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('problemColor = $problemColor');
    print('noProblemColor = $noProblemColor');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            fields[0]!,
            TextField(
              decoration:
              InputDecoration(filled: true, fillColor: toggleColor ? problemColor : noProblemColor),
              onChanged: ((val) {
                setState(() {
                  noProblemColor = const Color(0xfff44336);
                });
              }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```